# How to use an variable inside object declaration in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Am running this code in javascript..

```
function addEventToCalendar(date1, email){

          var date = date1+'T00:30:00.000Z';
          var event = {
            'summary': 'Event try1',
            'dateTime': date,
          }
}
```

I am obtaining a function parameter and using it for creating a variable called 
***date*** . when i try to use that variable inside the object called ***event***.. But when i do that, the variable is getting read as

```
'dateTime': ' 2017-02-22T00:30:00.000Z'
```

with ***space*** at the beginning. Because of this am not able to proceed further. How to avoid this

Comment: Well how are you creating date1? Make sure you aren't adding in a space when you are creating it. There is nothing in your currently shown code that would add a space

Comment: The space comes from `date1`. Either fix the calling of `addEventToCalendar` or call `trim` on `date1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `date.trim();`. This should remove the leading space.